# Finding the Greatest Coefficient in a Binomial Expansion?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

when I do this question, I try not using the: $(n-k+1)/k * b/a$ formula, but rather the $T(k+1)/T(k) ≥ 1$ formula. However, when I do it like that, I get the wrong answer - which is probably a simple algebraic mistake.

The question was: 
"Find the greatest coefficient in the expansion of $(1/3 +2x)^{18}$"

So can someone please, step by step, find the greatest coefficient using the $T(k+1)/T(k) ≥ 1$ formula?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what you mean by "the $T(k+1)/T(k)\ge1$ formula".

Comment: It means the coefficient of the T(k+1)th term divided by the T(k)th term

Answer (score 3):

Note that our expression is equal to $\frac{1}{3^{18}}(1+6x)^{18}$.

The coefficient of $x^{k+1}$ is $\binom{18}{k+1}6^{k+1}$. The coefficient of $x^k$ is $\binom{18}{k}6^{k}$. Divide. We get some immediate cancellation of powers of $6$, and of $18!$, and end up with the preliminary simplification
$$6\frac{k!(18-k)!}{(k+1)!(17-k)!}$$
and then 
$$6\frac{18-k}{k+1}.$$
We want to solve the inequality $6\frac{18-k}{k+1}\le 1$. Manipulation gives the equivalent $k\ge \frac{107}{7}\approx 15.3$. So the maximum coefficient is the coefficient of $x^{16}$.

Comment: Presumably you mean to compare $$6{18-k\over k+1}$$ to 1 before/while doing the arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, started skipping.

Comment: Why the greatest coefficient when $6\frac{18-k}{k+1}\le 1$?