# How to find the greatest absolute term in a binomial expansion

Tags: binomial-theorem

I know that the ratio of consecutive terms should be ≥1 and I'm able to solve using that approach but I was wondering whether we could derive a general formula and how would it work?

Comment: Have you read this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493903/finding-the-greatest-coefficient-in-a-binomial-expansion ?

Comment: Thanks but I want to find the greatest absolute term not the greatest coefficient

Answer (score 0):

My instantaneous thought on this is that the first binomial coefficient proceeds from the zeroth (1) by multiplying it by $n$; and the second by multiplying *that* by $(n-1)/2$, ... , & thereafter by $(n-k)/(k+1)$; and you're also multiplying by $x$ each time ... so the maximum term will be at the stationary point, when $(n-k)x=k+1$, and the increase 'turns round' to become a decrease. So you would have $$k≈\frac{nx-1}{x+1} ,$$ the "≈" taking account of the fact that it goes in integer steps, & $x$ need not be an integer.